# Get the very first -layoutSubviews call in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm constantly dealing with the recurring problem - I have to set up some things only once before view or view controllers appears. Usually frames should be already determined. For example when setting corner radius. So I find myself repeating the same pattern over and over in many classes. It goes like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL initialLayoutCompleted;

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (!self.initialLayoutCompleted) {

        self.initialLayoutCompleted = YES;
       //do initial set up.

    }

}
```

Is this the most efficient way? Is there something to simplify the condition check? Is there a better practice?

Comment: 1) Why worry about this? The view's frame could change and require new layout. 2) Always call `[super layoutSubview];` as the first line of your `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: @rmaddy 1) why shouldn't I worry about this? If something should be done only once, why would I want to do it probably hundreds of times with each layout call? 2) yes, you are right, and I do always call it, just didn't post it here to focus on the idea.

Comment: `layoutSubviews` could be called for various reasons that actually require that you layout the subviews based on the current state. Don't ignore those calls. Are you having a real issue due to too many calls to `layoutSubviews` or are you prematurely worrying about a possible issue? Don't fix things that aren't broken.

Comment: @rmaddy I know it can be called number of times. I use this pattern for example to set up a corner radius of an image view which size doesn't depend on layout. I don't want to hardcode a number, because if I change size in IB I will probably forget to change the number in code too.

Comment: Sounds like you are using `layoutSubviews` incorrectly. Why don't you update your question with a specific example and explain why you only want to do it once.